# Unusually low test coverage reported when using Cobertura with Gradle and Groovy code

Tags: groovy, gradle, cobertura

I'm developing a Gradle plugin and I'm trying to configure my project to let me get code coverage metrics on it. I have unit and integration tests based on the Spock framework.

I've tried using both Jacoco and Cobertura to analyse my project. Here is the configuration I'm working with:

```
Gradle:       2.2.1
Groovy:       2.3.6
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.3 compiled on December 23 2013
JVM:          1.8.0_25 (Oracle Corporation 25.25-b02)
OS:           Mac OS X 10.10.1 x86_64
```

I'm using the gradle-cobertura-plugin v2.2.5.

**Cobertura**

In the case of Cobertura, my project's reported line coverage is only 35%. There are large sections of code that I have written tests for that are reported as not tested by Cobertura:

[image: Cobertura coverage]

In particular, Cobertura reports no coverage for the nested static class `Version.Parser` despite there being a complete Spock specification devoted to this:

[image: Cobertura Version.Parser coverage]

```
package com.github.tagc.semver

import spock.lang.Specification
import spock.lang.Unroll

import com.github.tagc.semver.Version.Parser

@Unroll
class VersionParserSpec extends Specification {

    private static final Parser PARSER = Version.Parser.getInstance()

    def "Version information should be extracted from files if parsing is not strict"() {
        given:
        def versionFileText = "version='$versionString'"

        expect:
        PARSER.parse(versionFileText, false) == version

        where:
        versionString      | version
        '0.1.2-SNAPSHOT'   | new Version(0,1,2,false)
        '1.2.4'            | new Version(1,2,4,true)
        '1.3-SNAPSHOT'     | new Version(1,3,0,false)
        '0.4'              | new Version(0,4,0,true)
    }

    def "Valid version representation should be parsed successfully"() {
        expect:
        PARSER.parse(input, true) == version

        where:
        input               | version
        '0.1'               | new Version(0,1,0,true)
        '1.3-SNAPSHOT'      | new Version(1,3,0,false)
        '1.1.1'             | new Version(1,1,1,true)
        '0.2.7'             | new Version(0,2,7,true)
        '0.4.9-SNAPSHOT'    | new Version(0,4,9,false)
        '6.3.16-SNAPSHOT'   | new Version(6,3,16,false)
        '  1.2.3-SNAPSHOT'  | new Version(1,2,3,false)
        ' 1.3.5-SNAPSHOT '  | new Version(1,3,5,false)
    }

    def "Invalid version representation (#input) should cause an exception to be thrown"() {
        when:
        PARSER.parse(input, true)

        then:
        thrown(IllegalArgumentException)

        where:
        input << [
            '1.2.a',
            '1,2,3',
            '2.4.-1',
            '3-4-9',
            '1.4.5-SNPSHOT',
            '1.4.5-SNAPSHOTasd'
        ]
    }
}
```

Below are the relevant parts of my Gradle build script:

```
buildscript {
    repositories { jcenter() }
    dependencies {
        // Cobertura plugin
        classpath "net.saliman:gradle-cobertura-plugin:2.2.5"
    }
}

configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy {
        force 'org.ow2.asm:asm:5.0.3'
        forcedModules = [ 'org.ow2.asm:asm:5.0.3' ]
    }
}

apply plugin: 'net.saliman.cobertura'

check.dependsOn 'cobertura'

cobertura {
    coverageFormats = [ 'html', 'xml' ]
}
```

**Jacoco**

In comparison, Jacoco reports a much more plausible coverage of 68% (by instructions).

[image: Jacoco report]

Coverage of the same `Version.Parser` section is reported as this:

[image: Jacoco Version.Parser report]

The relevant parts of my build script are:

```
apply plugin: "jacoco"

task integrationTest(type: Test) {
    description = 'Runs the integration tests.'
    group = 'verification'
    testClassesDir = sourceSets.integrationTest.output.classesDir
    classpath = sourceSets.integrationTest.runtimeClasspath

    jacoco {
        destinationFile = file("$buildDir/jacoco/integrationTest.exec")
        classDumpFile = file("$buildDir/classes/integrationTest")
    }
}

jacocoTestReport {
    executionData test, integrationTest

    reports {
        xml.enabled true
        html.enabled true
    }
}
```

Since Jacoco seems to be working fine, I'd ideally like to just stick with it. However, Sonar doesn't seem to work properly with Jacoco when writing code in Groovy, so I seem to be stuck with Cobertura. Is there any reason why Cobertura could be giving me these coverage results?

**EDIT**

I have [raised this as an issue](https://github.com/stevesaliman/gradle-cobertura-plugin/issues/67) on the Gradle Cobertura plugin Github repository.

Comment: I'm no StackOverflow troll but I think you should consider posting the fix from the above link as a solution and except it so noone looks at this thinking it is an unsolved issue.

Comment: @ToddWCrone Sure thing.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tested it myself but apparently this issue is fixed as of v2.2.7 of the Gradle plugin, which uses v2.1.1 of Cobertura ([source](https://github.com/stevesaliman/gradle-cobertura-plugin/issues/67/)).